# apply a list of replacements on multiple xml files

Tags: xml, macros, replace

I need a solution for the next case.
I have a list of 60.000 words that i need to replace with the same word but with diacritics.

For example: "catre" -> "către"

This list i have to apply it on a bunch of xml files (about 20.000). The only solution i found was to make a macro in notepad++ with all the words and make the replacement on several files, but the macro contains for about 390.000 lines and it does not seem to works.

Is there a solution to this problem, a script, a program, something?

Thank you